# xparse \DeclareDocumentEnvironment does not print arguments in the end code section

Tags: xparse

I've been trying to create a custom environment for writing up my journal in LaTeX, but can't seem to get `xparse` to work right. When I use the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{entry}{m m}{#1}{#2}

\begin{document}
\begin{entry}{foo}{bar}
Test phrase
\end{entry}
\end{document}
```

all I get is:

> foo Test phrase

without the `bar`! Is there something I'm missing here, or is this a bug?

EDIT: Just tried it on my other machine and it compiles fine with xparse 2012/11/12 v4332. I guess it's an out date xparse on my other machine. Thanks!

Comment: This works as intended on my system producing:  foo Test phrase bar

Comment: Does that exact code fail on your system?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I also get the correct results of `foo Test phrase bar` using TeXLive 2010, 2011 and the an updated 2012. Are you perhaps on an older release?  You can add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}` to see the versions of the pacakges included. My `xparse` version is `2012/09/29 v4249`.

Comment: @user23103: It seems that you are the same user who posted the original question. Please confirm so that the accounts can be merged.

Comment: There was a bug in some releases in this regard, but it is fixed as noted in the edit. I've therefore closed as too localized (in time).